# this.$modal.one(...).modal is not a function Cropper - Symfony 3

Tags: jquery, cropper

I've implemented the jQuery Cropper module using PrestaImageBundle for Symfony 3 (alongside VichUploader for uploading the images) and I'm having this error pop up when trying to upload. It seems to be pointing to this function, when it's attempting to create the modal in order to crop the uploaded image:

```
   /**
     * Open cropper "editor" in a modal with the base64 uploaded image.
     *
     * @param {string} base64
     */
    Cropper.prototype.prepareCropping = function(base64) {
        var self = this;

        // clean previous croppable image
        this.$container.$preview.children('img').cropper('destroy').remove();

        // reset "aspectRatio" buttons
        this.$aspectRatio.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);

            if ($this.val().length <= 0) {
                $this.trigger('click');
            }
        });

        this.$modal
            .one('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                // (re)build croppable image once the modal is shown (required to get proper image width)
                $('<img>')
                    .attr('src', base64)
                    .on('load', function() {
                        $(this).cropper(self.options);
                    })
                    .appendTo(self.$container.$preview);
            })
            .modal('show');
    };
```

I installed the cropper library using `npm install cropper` (i.e. the one dependent on jQuery which I have) and included that before the PrestaImageBundle cropper.js file as explained [here](https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaImageBundle) but I cannot see what the issue is, as everything else seems to work, the config is correct and the button appears and allows me to select an image - it just fails to produce the modal once I've selected the image from my computer.

If anyone else has encountered this issue, help would be appreciated as I really think this bundle is what I need, and I'd been searching for something for a while so it's a shame if I cannot get it working.

EDIT:

Initialising Cropper:

```
(function(w, $) {

'use strict';

$(function() {
    $('.cropper').each(function() {
        new Cropper($(this));
    });
});

})(window, jQuery);
```

The js includes in the base file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('cropper/dist/cropper.min.js') }}"></script> {# from the offcial cropper repo #}
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/cropper.js') }}"></script> {# PrestaImageBundle's modifications where this.$modal is called #}
```

The cropper.js initElements function:

```
Cropper.prototype.initElements = function() {
    this.$modal = this.$el.find('.modal');
    this.$aspectRatio = this.$modal.find('input[name="cropperAspectRatio"]');
    this.$input = this.$el.find('input.cropper-base64');

    this.$container = {
        $preview: this.$modal.find('.cropper-preview'),
        $canvas: this.$el.find('.cropper-canvas-container')
    };

    this.$local = {
        $btnUpload: this.$el.find('.cropper-local button'),
        $input: this.$el.find('.cropper-local input[type="file"]')
    };

    this.$remote = {
        $btnUpload: this.$el.find('.cropper-remote button'),
        $uploadLoader: this.$el.find('.cropper-remote .remote-loader'),
        $input: this.$el.find('.cropper-remote input[type="url"]')
    };

    this.options = $.extend(this.options, {
        aspectRatio: this.$aspectRatio.val()
    });

    return this;
};
```

the Form Type for the image upload:

```
$builder->add('imageFile', ImageType::class, array(
    'upload_mimetype' => 'image/jpeg',
    'download_link' => false
));
```

The Twig template with the form:

```
{{ form_start(image_form) }}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_widget(image_form.imageFile, { 'class': 'cropper' }) }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{ form_end(image_form) }}
```

**ADDITIONAL EDIT: Looking into the documentation closer, I believe that it should be `this.$modal.on()` not `this.$modal.one()` but even changing this still results in the same issue.**

Comment: what is this.$modal 's selector or what value did you assign for this.$modal?

Comment: make sure if you have included the proper modal code. Looks like you are using bootstrap. so double check if you have loaded the bootstrap script before executing this code

Comment: Ye, both jQuery and Bootstrap are loaded first. Everything else initalises, it's only that one line that seems to fail - is modal a different plugin?

Comment: modal's code should be there within bootstrap js. can you show the dom structure of modal and how you are initializing this.$modal ?

Comment: I have edited the question and added more code snippets, including the script includes and the initalisation of Cropper and the forms.

Comment: Just to clarify, the code works because the upload functionality is embedded in the page - it's just as soon as you choose an image that the modal error appears.